# How to make fingerprints only depend on scalar results

Tags: omnet++

I'm trying to use fingerprint tests for feature tests of our simulation library. There is the s option that allows to include only scalar recordings into the fingerprints. However the fingerprints change in our simulations even if the numbers in the scalar results stay the same. Are events maybe somehow included in the fingerprints, even if I only use the s parameter to create fingerprints?

I'm using Omnetpp 5.5.1 and INET 4.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for changes in all scalars, or just some of them?
If you change the model, it might lead to subtle changes in the timings, and in turn in some scalars as well.